# Getting this error while running npm start in terminal vs code

Tags: reactjs, react-native

Getting this error while running npm start in terminal vs code:

npm ERR! code ENOENT

npm ERR! syscall open

npm ERR! path D:\1 last try/package.json

npm ERR! errno -4058

npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'D:\1 last try\package.json'

npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
npm ERR! enoent

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Acer\AppData\Local\npm-cache_logs\2021-12-13T12_38_55_514Z-debug.log

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J03tt.png)

Comment: just a quick check, if you are on correct directory or not

Comment: Hi bro i am on the correct one

Answer (score 0):

This error is likely due to a missing `package.json` file at your current directory. To create a new `package.json` in this directory, you can use `npm init`. It will prompt you for some metadata and automatically generate your `package.json` file.

I assume you are looking to run something similar to [`create-react-app`](https://reactjs.org/docs/create-a-new-react-app.html) based on the attempt to run the `start` script and the directory being named `react-website-v1`. In order to initialize a CRA site, the [official documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/create-a-new-react-app.html) lists the commands for doing so as follows:

> ```
> npx create-react-app my-app
> cd my-app
> npm start
> ```